# Hash of hashes from an array

Tags: ruby

From an array:

```
this = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I am trying to create a hash of hashes:

```
{{num: 1}, {num: 2}, {num: 3}, {num: 4}, {num: 5}}
```

But I'm getting an empty hash:

```
Hash.new(this.each do |num| Hash.new(num: num) end)
# => {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That returns an array of hashes though.

Comment: {{num: 1}, {num: 2}, {num: 3}, {num: 4}, {num: 5}} is not a valid hash, and a hash can not have the same key for more than once.

Comment: Please provide your desired output. The data structure you posted as your desired output is not a legal Ruby data structure. It isn't even legal Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your desired result in your question doesn't make sense since you're using the Hash `{}` syntax, but there are no keys. It seems as though you want your result to be an array of hashes.

Second, you're confusing `each` with `map`. `each` simply iterates through an array, passing each item to the block. The return value of `arr.each` is just `arr`. `map`, on the other hand, returns a new array based on the return value of the block:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map { |item| { num: item } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the default value (furthermore with a block that does not do anything meaningful) without setting any key-value pairs.

Comment: I see. Each inner hash I mentioned doesn't have a key